# What does 'sell out something' mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is an example:

> I know the feelings away, uh
>
> I will sell out my shit some more, ah
>
> But I feel like a MAD MAN!

I know sell out means to sell all things and it's often used with selling tickets at some concert, but I don't think he is saying about selling his music in the future. Help me, please.

Comment: For the common slang definition see number 2 [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/sell-out_1).  But there's not enough context in your example to know if this is actually what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a sentence from a song. Song lyrics are often can't be 'interpreted' normally, however, probably we can at least understand what the writer wants to say. From the song, this sounds a 'depressing song'

[image: Song by scarlxrd]

From that song, it can mean anything actually. But I've got a feeling that it means kind like you betray your friends or colleagues (sold out your friend for something..) and the writer said in previous sentence:

> I know the feelings away, uh = he knows that (actually he doesn't really want to do it thus the feelings are off/away)

[image]

> I will **sell out** my shit some more, ah (so he will lie/ more with 'some shit'.. shit can mean anything from something cool to tease or try to deceive (someone) or just an angry shout..

Let's see:

From Webster:

> "**sell out** **verb**

Definition of sell out (Entry 2 of 2)

> **transitive verb**
>
> 1 : to sell the goods of (a debtor) in order to satisfy creditors
>
> 2 : to sell security or commodity holdings of usually to satisfy an uncovered margin
>
> 3a : to sell all the available tickets for sold out the concert
>
> b : to sell all of the merchandise was quickly sold out

**intransitive verb**

> 1 : to dispose of one's goods by sale especially : to sell one's business
>
> 2 : to betray one's cause or associates especially for personal gain
>
> 3 : to be or achieve a sellout

For the best interpretation of the song lyric, you can consult the songwriter:

> Songwriters: **Carlton Mays / Marius Listhrop**

Comment: ahahah, ok, I will chat with the songwriter (no), I guessed about cheating...so Thank you man, really!

Comment: You present a lot of information, but it seems like you don't really answer the question.  It would be a better answer if you specified which definitions of "shit" and "sell out" are most likely in the context of the rest of the lyrics, since, obviously, Дмитрий can't ask the songwriter directly.  It's not like this song is particularly deep.

Comment: @Andrew Hi Andrew, the answer is actually there (in the definition).

Comment: @Flonne  Yes, "sell out" has many definitions.  Can you indicate more clearly, perhaps at the *top* of the answer, which one you think applies here?  However, with slang and other colloquial uses, you can not rely too much on standard dictionaries, as the phrase might have a different meaning from what they mention, or they may not list all possible meanings.  In this case "to sell out" most likely means **"to do something that shows you no longer have the same moral principles that you used to have"**.  This is a relatively common use when applied to art or music.